# How to solve "The stock item was unable to be saved"?

Tags: magento2, upgrade, magento2.3.3

I was using the Magento 2.3.2 normally, but since I updated to Magento 2.3.3 I'm not able to create a new product anymore. I'm receiving this message below.

> The stock item was unable to be saved. Please try again.

[image: Magento 2 The stock item was unable to be saved]

My **exception.log** is logging this message:

> [2019-11-06 17:30:42] main.CRITICAL: The stock item was unable to be saved. Please try again. {"exception":"[object] (Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotSaveException(code: 0): The stock item was unable to be saved. Please try again. at /Users/rafael/dev/mystoremagento/vendor/magento/module-catalog-inventory/Model/Stock/StockItemRepository.php:187, Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotSaveException(code: 0): Could not save Source Item at /Users/rafael/dev/mystoremagento/vendor/magento/module-inventory/Model/SourceItem/Command/Handler/SourceItemsSaveHandler.php:78, Zend_Db_Statement_Exception(code: 23000): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mystoremagento`.`inventory_source_item`, CONSTRAINT `INVENTORY_SOURCE_ITEM_SOURCE_CODE_INVENTORY_SOURCE_SOURCE_CODE` FOREIGN KEY (`source_code`) REFERENCES `inventory_source` (`source_code`) ), query was: INSERT INTO `inventory_source_item` (`source_code`, `sku`, `quantity`, `status`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `quantity` = VALUES(`quantity`), `status` = VALUES(`status`) at /Users/rafael/dev/mystoremagento/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php:110, PDOException(code: 23000): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mystoremagento`.`inventory_source_item`, CONSTRAINT `INVENTORY_SOURCE_ITEM_SOURCE_CODE_INVENTORY_SOURCE_SOURCE_CODE` FOREIGN KEY (`source_code`) REFERENCES `inventory_source` (`source_code`) ) at /Users/rafael/dev/mystoremagento/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php:91)"} []

Even doing these tests it doesn't work:

- Disabling all third-party module
- Running the install process (using the same DB)
- Exporting and importing the DB

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it **removing all Magento MSI modules** running these commands:

```
composer require yireo/magento2-replace-inventory:2.3.*
bin/magento s:upgrade
bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento cache:flush
bin/magento index:reindex
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing this issue and MSI removal not being an option, make sure a "Stores->(Inventory) Sources" with source code `default` exists. There's a hardcoded fallback to it.

Other stuff to try:

- set all your indexers to "On Schedule";
- make sure to have one entry on table `cataloginventory_stock` with id 1 and the stock name "Default";